# TikZ: labeling a small arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, automation

How can I automate labeling a small arc?

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) arc[radius = .25cm, start angle = 0, end angle = 30];
  \draw (-.01, .07) arc[radius =.25cm, start angle = 90, end angle = -90]
  node[left] {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I had to play around with `(-.01, .07)` for the labeling arc.  However, if the arc moves, the label isn't in the correct location.  This example is rather simple but this has to do with changing hyperbola and/or rotating it.  When this occurs, the vectors will change position and increase or decrease the angle between them.  Unfortunately, the labeling arc will remain put.  How can I have the arc adjust with the changing of the figure?

---

Just for reference, here is a picture of the actual figure:

[image]

If anything is changed, everything but the arc and alpha_2 will adjust automatically.  I would like to have the arc and alpha_2 built into the adjustments.

Again for reference, here is the main figure code:

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}           
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}                                                 
\linespread{1.05}                          
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}                                                     
\usepackage{courier}                                                            
\usepackage{eulervm}                        
\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style = {font = \tiny},
  line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45
  ]
  \def\angle{50}
  \def\peri{.5}
  \def\planet{.4}
  \def\a{1.25}

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a / tan(\angle)}

  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (3.5, 0) node[below left, font = \tiny] {\(\mathbf{V}\)};
  \draw[-latex] (3.5, 0) -- +(1, 0) node[right, font = \tiny]
  {\(\hat{\mathbf{u}}_V\)};
  \draw[-latex] (0, 3.5) -- +(0, 1) node[above, font = \tiny]
  {\(\hat{\mathbf{u}}_S\)};
  \draw[thick, gray, name path global = soi] (O) circle[radius = 3.5cm];

  \begin{scope}[rotate = {110}, shift = {(0, {-\a - \peri})},
    decoration = {markings,
      mark = at position 0.20 with {\arrow{latex}},
      mark = at position 0.80 with {\arrow{latex}}
    }]
    \draw[red, postaction = decorate, name path global = hyper]
    plot[domain = -2.95:2.95, samples = 100]
    ({\x}, {\a * sqrt(1 + (\x / \b)^2)});
    \draw[dashed] plot[domain = 0:3, samples = 100] ({\x}, {\a / \b * \x})
    coordinate (P1);

    \path plot[domain = 0:-3, samples = 100] ({\x}, {-\a / \b * \x})
    coordinate (P2);

    \draw[dashed] plot[domain = -3:0, samples = 100] ({\x}, {-\a / \b * \x})
    coordinate (I);
    \draw plot[domain = 0:.5, samples = 100] ({\x}, {-\a / \b * \x})
    coordinate (P3);
    \draw[dashed] (O) -- (I);

    \shadedraw[gray, inner color = blue!40!green,
    outer color = black!50!blue!50] (O) circle[radius = \planet];

    \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
      \p0 = (I),
      \p1 = (O),
      \p2 = (P1),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {.75cm},
      \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
    in (I) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at (\n4:\n3) {\(\beta\)};

    \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
      \p0 = (I),
      \p1 = (O),
      \p2 = (P2),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {.75cm},
      \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
    in (I) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at (\n4:\n3) {\(\beta\)};

    \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
      \p0 = (I),
      \p1 = (P1),
      \p2 = (P3),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {.75cm},
      \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
    in (I) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at (\n4:\n3) {\(\delta\)};
  \end{scope}

  \node[name intersections = {of = soi and hyper}] (P4) at
  ($(intersection-2)$) {};

  \draw[-latex] (P4.center) -- +(1.5, 0) node[font = \tiny, below left]
  {\(\mathbf{V}\)} coordinate (P5);
  \draw (P5) -- +(.5, 0) coordinate (P6);

  \path[name path global = circ] (P4.center) circle[radius = 1bp];
  \path[name intersections = {of = circ and hyper}] (P4.center) --
  ($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$) coordinate (P7);

  \draw[-latex] (P5) -- +($(P7) - (P4)$) node[font = \tiny, right]
  {\(\mathbf{v}_{\infty_1}\)} coordinate (P8);
  \draw[-latex] (P4.center) -- (P8) node[font = \tiny, fill = white,
  inner sep = 0, pos = .65] {\(\mathbf{V}_1^{(v)}\)};

  \node[name intersections = {of = soi and hyper}] (P9) at ($(intersection-1)$)
  {};

  \draw[-latex] (P9.center) -- +(1.5, 0) node[font = \tiny, below left]
  {\(\mathbf{V}\)} coordinate (P10);
  \draw (P10) -- +(.65, 0) coordinate (P11);

  \path[name path global = circ2] (P9.center) circle[radius = 1bp];
  \path[name intersections = {of = circ2 and hyper}] (P9.center) --
  ($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$) coordinate (P12);

  \draw[-latex] (P10) -- +($(P12) - (P9)$) node[font = \tiny, right]
  {\(\mathbf{v}_{\infty_2}\)} coordinate (P13);
  \draw[-latex] (P9.center) -- (P13) node[font = \tiny, fill = white,
  inner sep = 0, pos = .5, above = .1cm] {\(\mathbf{V}_2^{(v)}\)};

  \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
    \p0 = (P4.center),
    \p1 = (P5),
    \p2 = (P8),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.5cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P4.center) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2] node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at
  ([shift = (P4.center)] \n4:.75cm) {\(\alpha_1\)};

  \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
    \p0 = (P5),
    \p1 = (P6),
    \p2 = (P8),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.45cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P5) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2] node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at
  ([shift = (P5)] \n4:.63cm) {\(\phi_1\)};

  \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
    \p0 = (P9.center),
    \p1 = (P10),
    \p2 = (P13),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.5cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P9.center) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2];

  \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
    \p0 = (P10),
    \p1 = (P11),
    \p2 = (P13),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.65cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P10) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2] node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at
  ([shift = (P10)] \n4:\n3) {\(\phi_2\)};

  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw[dashed] (O) -- +($(O) - 0.65*(I)$) coordinate (P14);
  \end{scope}

  \draw[latex-] (P14) -- +($(P4) - (P7)$) node[font = \tiny, right]
  {\(\mathbf{v}_{\infty_1}\)} coordinate (P15);
  \draw[-latex] (P15) -- +($(P12) - (P9)$) node[font = \tiny, below]
  {\(\mathbf{v}_{\infty_2}\)} coordinate (P16);
  \draw[-latex] (P14) -- (P16) node[font = \tiny, pos = .5, above]
  {\(\Delta\mathbf{V}^{(v)}\)};

  \draw let
    \p0 = (P15),
    \p1 = (P14),
    \p2 = (P16),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.25cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P15) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2] node[inner sep = 0, font = \tiny, inner sep = 0,
  fill = white] at ([shift = (P15)] \n4:\n3) {\(\delta\)};

  \draw (-2.32, 2.15) arc[radius = .25cm, start angle = 90, end angle = -90]
  node[left, font = \tiny] {\(\alpha_2\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Your angle annotations are pretty unconventional and in my personal opinion quite confusing. Have a look at slide 8 of [this](http://engineering.pages.tcnj.edu/files/2012/02/dimensioning_and_tolerancing.pdf) fpr the standard if the dimension text doesn't fit inside the angle arms. Alternatively you can extend the angle arms and annotate somewhere less crowded. You can at least use arrow heads for the arcs such that it resembles an angular dimension

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myarc[5]{%
  \draw (#1) arc [radius = #2, start angle = #3, end angle = #4];
  \draw let 
      \p0 = (#1),
      \n1 = { (#3 + #4) / 2},
      \n2 = { (180 - #3) }
    in  (#1) ++(\n2:#2) + (\n1:#2) coordinate (#5);
  \draw (#1) + ((#3+#4)/2:#2) coordinate (#5);
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myarc{0,0}{.25cm}{0}{30}{arccentre}
  \draw (arccentre) arc[radius =.25cm, start angle = 90, end angle = -90]
  node[left] {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you could define an intermediate node from which you start with `(start) + (angel:radius) arc ...`.