# I am having an issue with an included standalone TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I am not sure if code will do much good here.  I have included many standalone `TikZ` pictures but this pictures is the only one to act differently.

Here is the picture in compiled from the standalone `.tex` code.

[image]

Now here is the picture in the main `.tex` file.  Notice the location of the `alpha_2` and the arc in the main file which I just compiled again to verify everything was updated.

[image]

I don't know what to do about this discrepancy and how to correct it.  The image is a previous run of the standalone that was incorrect.  However, it refuses to update.  This has never been an issue before.

---

In the main file, I am using the following code to include the `TikZ` picture.
Additionally, I have `\usepackage{standalone}` in the preample of the main file.

```
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includestandalone{flybytrailingside}
  \caption[Trailing Side Flyby]{A trailing side (or sunlit side) planetary           
    flyby.}
  \label{trailingflyby}
\end{figure*}
```

For the `TikZ` picture, I am using the document class `standalone` and then drawing the picture.

The code for `\alpha_2` is

```
\draw (3.285, 2.15) arc[radius = .125, start angle = 90, end angle = -90]
  node[left, font = \tiny, inner sep = 0] {\(\alpha_2\)};
```

---

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}          
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}                   
\linespread{1.05}                
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}                                              
\usepackage{courier}                                                           
\usepackage{eulervm}                      
\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style = {font = \tiny},
  line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45,
  %scale = .04, transform shape                                                     
  ]
  \def\angle{45}
  \def\peri{.5}
  \def\planet{.4}
  \def\a{1}
  \def\circrad{3.5}
  \def\dom{3.15}

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a / (tan(\angle))}

  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (\circrad, 0) node[below left, font = \tiny]
  {\(\mathbf{V}\)};
  \draw[-latex] (\circrad, 0) -- +({1}, 0) node[right, font = \tiny]
  {\(\hat{\mathbf{u}}_V\)};
  \draw[-latex] (0, \circrad) -- +(0, {1}) node[above, font = \tiny]
  {\(\hat{\mathbf{u}}_S\)};
  \draw[thick, gray, name path global = soi] (O)
  circle[radius = \circrad];

  \begin{scope}[rotate = {-110}, shift = {(0, {-\a - \peri})},
    decoration = {markings,
      mark = at position 0.20 with {\arrow{latex reversed}},
      mark = at position 0.80 with {\arrow{latex reversed}}
    }]
    \draw[red, postaction = decorate, name path global = hyper]
    plot[domain = -\dom:\dom, samples = 500]
    ({\x}, {\a * sqrt(1 + (\x / \b)^2)});
    \draw[dashed] plot[domain = 0:\dom, samples = 100] ({\x}, {\a / \b * \x})
    coordinate (P1);

    \path plot[domain = 0:-\dom, samples = 100] ({\x}, {-\a / \b * \x})
    coordinate (P2);

    \draw[dashed] plot[domain = -\dom:0, samples = 100] ({\x}, {-\a / \b * \x})
    coordinate (I);
    \draw plot[domain = 0:.5, samples = 100] ({\x}, {-\a / \b * \x})
    coordinate (P3);
    \draw[dashed] (O) -- (I);

    \shadedraw[gray, inner color = blue!40!green,
    outer color = black!50!blue!50] (O) circle[radius = \planet];

    \draw[fixed point arithmetic, latex-latex] let
      \p0 = (I),
      \p1 = (O),
      \p2 = (P1),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {.75cm},
      \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
    in (I) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at (\n4:.5cm) {\(\beta\)};

    \draw[fixed point arithmetic, latex-latex] let
      \p0 = (I),
      \p1 = (O),
      \p2 = (P2),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {.75cm},
      \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
    in (I) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at (\n4:.5cm) {\(\beta\)};

    \draw[fixed point arithmetic, -latex] let
      \p0 = (I),
      \p1 = (P3),
      \p2 = (P1),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {.75cm},
      \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
    in (I) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at (\n4:\n3) {\(\delta\)};
  \end{scope}

  \node[name intersections = {of = soi and hyper}] (P4) at
  ($(intersection-2)$) {};

  \draw[-latex] (P4.center) -- +(1.5, 0) node[font = \tiny, below left]
  {\(\mathbf{V}\)} coordinate (P5);
  \draw (P5) -- +(.5, 0) coordinate (P6);

  \path[name path global = circ] (P4.center) circle[radius = 1bp];
  \path[name intersections = {of = circ and hyper}] (P4.center) --
  ($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$) coordinate (P7);

  \draw[-latex] (P5) -- +($(P7) - (P4)$) node[font = \tiny, right]
  {\(\mathbf{v}_{\infty_1}\)} coordinate (P8);
  \draw[-latex] (P4.center) -- (P8) node[font = \tiny, above,
  inner sep = 0, pos = .65] {\(\mathbf{V}_1^{(v)}\)};

  \node[name intersections = {of = soi and hyper}] (P9) at ($(intersection-1)$)
  {};

  \draw[-latex] (P9.center) -- +(1.5, 0) node[font = \tiny, below left]
  {\(\mathbf{V}\)} coordinate (P10);
  \draw (P10) -- +(.65, 0) coordinate (P11);

  \path[name path global = circ2] (P9.center) circle[radius = 1bp];
  \path[name intersections = {of = circ2 and hyper}] (P9.center) --
  ($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$) coordinate (P12);

  \draw[-latex] (P10) -- +($(P12) - (P9)$) node[font = \tiny, pos =1.25]
  {\(\mathbf{v}_{\infty_2}\)} coordinate (P13);
  \draw[-latex] (P9.center) -- (P13) node[font = \tiny, fill = white,
  inner sep = 0, pos = .5, above = .1cm] {\(\mathbf{V}_2^{(v)}\)};

  \draw[fixed point arithmetic, -latex] let
    \p0 = (P4.center),
    \p1 = (P5),
    \p2 = (P8),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.75cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P4.center) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2] node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at
  ([shift = (P4.center)] \n4:1cm) {\(\alpha_1\)};

  \draw[fixed point arithmetic, -latex] let
    \p0 = (P5),
    \p1 = (P6),
    \p2 = (P8),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.45cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P5) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2] node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at
  ([shift = (P5)] \n4:\n3) {\(\phi_1\)};
  %{\pgfmathparse{\n2 - \n1}%                                                       
  %  $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^{\circ}$                                  
  %};                                                                               

  \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
    \p0 = (P9.center),
    \p1 = (P10),
    \p2 = (P13),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.5cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P9.center) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2];

  \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
    \p0 = (P10),
    \p1 = (P11),
    \p2 = (P13),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.5cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P10) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2] node[fill = white, inner sep = 0, font = \tiny] at
  ([shift = (P10)] \n4:.7cm) {\(\phi_2\)};
  %{\pgfmathparse{\n2 - \n1}%                                                       
  %  $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^{\circ}$                                  
  %};                                                                               

  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw[dashed] (O) -- +($(O) - 0.65*(I)$) coordinate (P14);
  \end{scope}

  \draw[latex-] (P14) -- +($(P4) - (P7)$) node[font = \tiny, left]
  {\(\mathbf{v}_{\infty_1}\)} coordinate (P15);
  \draw[-latex] (P15) -- +($(P12) - (P9)$) node[font = \tiny, below]
  {\(\mathbf{v}_{\infty_2}\)} coordinate (P16);
  \draw[-latex] (P14) -- (P16) node[font = \tiny, pos = .75, above]
  {\(\Delta\mathbf{V}^{(v)}\)};

  \draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
    \p0 = (P15),
    \p1 = (P14),
    \p2 = (P16),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.25cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (P15) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
  end angle = \n2] node[inner sep = 0, font = \tiny, inner sep = 0,
  fill = white] at ([shift = (P15)] \n4:\n3) {\(\delta\)};

  \draw (3.285, 2.15) arc[radius = .125, start angle = 90, end angle = -90]
  node[left, font = \tiny, inner sep = 0] {\(\alpha_2\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add that this problem just occurred again with a new standalone.
Here is the picture compiled from the standalone:

[image]

and here is the picture in the document:

This picture was just created, compiled, then added to the main document, and compiled.  The code can be found here:

[TikZ: drawing an evolution of an ellipse to a hyperbola with the same focus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126249/tikz-drawing-an-evolution-of-an-ellipse-to-a-hyperbola-with-the-same-focus/126277#126277)

[image]

Comment: I don't think someone will have a chance to help without the code. I think something wrong with the sizes: used absolute values (`pt`, `px`) insted of relative (`em`, `ex`).

Comment: (unrelated: That's a really nice image, by the way. Very clear and organised!)

Comment: @dustin: Well then there's something wrong with how you place `\alpha_2` and the arc, as m0nhawk said. You will need to post the code in this case.

Comment: @dustin: And how do you generate and position the small angle that `\alpha_2` refers to?

Comment: @dustin: Hehe, I'm not particularly fond of the arcs for the labels either, I would probably just have used a straight line that points to the small angle.

Comment: @dustin: Yes, please. I think this is a case where it makes sense to just dump the whole code.

Comment: @Jake I added the whole code for the standalone.

Comment: I can not help, but I believe that others that can will benefit from a MWE from you. Have you tried to remove non-relevant lines from your code? -possible all other lines than the offending `\alpha_2`?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Jake wanted me to dump the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should calculate the coordinate of the arc of $\alpha_2$ instead of providing a fixed number.

The corresponding arc is

```
\draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
  \p0 = (P9.center),
  \p1 = (P10),
  \p2 = (P13),
  \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
  \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
  \n3 = {.5cm},
  \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
    in (P9.center) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1,
    end angle = \n2];
```

If you can copy this section and use `\n4` for the position of the arc:

```
\draw[fixed point arithmetic] let
  \p0 = (P9.center),
  \p1 = (P10),
  \p2 = (P13),
  \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
  \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
  \n3 = {.5cm},
  \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
    in (P9.center) +(\n4:\n3) coordinate (test);
  \draw (test)
     %(3.285cm, 2.15cm) 
     arc[radius = .125, start angle = 90, end angle = -90]
     node[left, font = \tiny, inner sep = 0] {\(\alpha_2\)};
```

BTW.: If you try to scale the figure even by small amounts (factor 0.96) you get “interesting” results.

So propably you are using different TikZ settings as in the standalone file.

Comment: I am not scaling the figures at all.

Comment: I just tried your answer, and I like using this method here.  I believe I have an open question to automating this process.  Your answer here would solve that question.  I need to now check if it fixes the `standalone` issue.

Comment: I can mimic your answer to solve [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125950/tikz-labeling-a-small-arc) question but you should get the credit.  So if you want you can provide the answer there.  The problem is different but similar.