# TikZ: drawing an evolution of an ellipse to a hyperbola with the same focus

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, foreach

Is there a high speed way to draw the evolution of an ellipse, to a parabola, and then into a few hyperbolas with the same focus?

[image]

From the picture, we see that we start out with three elliptical orbits around Earth all with Earth being the focus.  The ellipse progress from no intersection with the moons orbit, to a Hohmann transfer ellipse, and then an ellipse with to intersections.  After the ellipse evolution, the next orbit is parabolic and then it finishes with three hyperbolic orbits.

I could draw all these individually, but I believe there could be a way to do this without such a tedious method.

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}

%\usepackage{fp}                                                                    
%\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}                         
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}                                                 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (E) at (0, 0);

  \def\moonrad{4cm}

  \draw (E) [partial circle = -15:150:\moonrad];
  \shadedraw[gray, left color = orange!75!blue, right color = blue!75!black]
  (E) circle[radius = .3cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Using percusse idea, I have constructed the ellipse, parabola, and hyperbolas.
Unfortunately, I am not sure how I can shift them in the `\foreach` command to place them all at `(0, -.5)`.

```
  \coordinate (E) at (0, 0);

  \def\moonrad{4cm}
  \def\dom{3}

  \draw (E) [partial circle = -15:150:\moonrad];
  \shadedraw[gray, left color = orange!75!blue, right color = blue!75!black]
  (E) circle[radius = .2cm];

  \foreach \a/\b/\type in {.75/1/dashed, 1.25/2.25/dotted, 1.5/3/}{
    \draw[\type] (0, -.5) arc[x radius = \a, y radius = \b, start angle =-90,
    end angle = 270];
  }

  \begin{scope}[shift = {(0, -.5)}]
    \draw plot[domain = 0:\dom, samples = 500] ({\x}, {.5 * (\x)^2});
  \end{scope}

  \foreach \a/\angle in {1.5/30, 2/45, 3/60}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a / tan(\angle)}
    \draw plot[domain = 0:\dom, samples = 500]
    ({\x}, {\a * sqrt(1 + (\x / \b)^2)});
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use percusse answer but add to it to achieve the desired result.

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  partial circle/.style args = {#1:#2:#3}{
    insert path = {+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45,
  every label/.append style = {font = \scriptsize},
  dot/.style = {inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle,
    draw = black, label = {#1}},
  small dot/.style = {minimum size = .05cm, dot = {#1}},
  big dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
  ]
  \coordinate (E) at (0, 0);

  \def\moonrad{4cm}
  \def\dom{3.1}

  \draw (E) [partial circle = -15:150:\moonrad];
  \shadedraw[gray, left color = orange!75!blue, right color = blue!75!black]
  (E) circle[radius = .2cm];

  \foreach \a/\b/\type in {.75/1/dashed, 1.25/2.25/dotted, 1.5/3/}{
    \draw[\type] (0, -.5) arc[x radius = \a, y radius = \b, start angle =-90,
    end angle = 270];
  }

  \begin{scope}[shift = {(0, -.5)}]
    \draw plot[domain = 0:\dom, samples = 500] ({\x}, {.5 * (\x)^2});
  \end{scope}

  \foreach \a/\angle/\i in {1.5/30/3, 2/45/2.1, 3/60/1}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a / tan(\angle)}
    \begin{scope}[shift = {(0, -\a - .5)}]
      \draw plot[domain = 0:{\dom + \i}, samples = 500]
      ({\x}, {\a * sqrt(1 + (\x / \b)^2)});
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now all I need to do is adjust the hyperbolas how I like.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something along the lines of

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\clip (-4cm,-2.5cm) rectangle (5cm,5cm);
\draw (3.5cm,-2cm) arc (0:150:3.5 cm);

\foreach \x/\y in {1/dashed,1.5/dotted,2.5/}{
\draw[\y] (0,-2) arc (-90:270:0.5cm+3*\x mm and \x cm);
}

\foreach \x in {10,25,50,75}{
\draw[] (0,-2) arc (-90:30:0.5cm+3*\x mm and \x cm);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]